# Adding field to Wordpress admin Quick Edit

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, jigoshop

I have new client whose web site uses an older version of Jigoshop (0.9.9) that has
had a lot of customization done to it. They want me to add the pricing field to the
admin's quick edit panel for each product.

The field name in question is 'regular_price'.

How do I go about adding a custom field to the quick edit panel?

Many thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I've been stymied on this from the get-go. I'm not even sure which file(s) govern the quick end panel.

Comment: Have you tried [searching](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/expand-the-wordpress-quick-edit-menu) for it?

Comment: I saw that - but given that the field and the column are already created, it seemed like more info than I needed, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older question but I have recently tried doing this as well and I did find this plugin I haven't fully implemented it yet but thought it might be able to help you unless you found another way around it.  I see @Jonas G. Drange has the coding way of going about it but I didn't necessarily want to mess with that so found this plugin.  If it works for you let me know!

[Custom Bulk/Quick Edit](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-bulkquick-edit/)

Answer (score -3):

if you don't wanna mess with coding, you can try the [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

Comment: The ACF plugin doesn't currently support "Quick Edit", as the OP mentioned. One can manually add exceptions to allow this to happen via the functions.php file for a theme, but it's a manual process. The only thing ACF does is "create" the custom fields. It won't add them to the Quick Edit feature within WordPress, however.